# How to obtain name of input variable of the procedure (PLSQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sqlplus

Let's say I have procedure called myProc(variable varchar2);

Then I call it:

```
exec myProc(actionVariable);
```

Is there a way, how to obtain 'actionVariable' as a string in procedure myProc? So when I use procedure differently:

```
exec myProc(anotherVariable);
```

I'll obtain 'anotherVariable' as a string in procedure myProc.

Thanks. I only found that I can obtain origin variable name with 'select argument_name from user_arguments....'

Comment: No. Why would it be useful to know the local, private name that your caller uses for their variable? If it even has a name - what would you expect if a literal was passed, `exec myProc('Some string value')`? If you only have a very small set of callers I guess you could add another argument and make them set that to their local variable name, but what would be the point?

Comment: You're right. I just need simple usability of "myProc". Need to implement it's funcionality by just adding one row (no declaring variables etc.). And I need the name, because it has standard structure of name from which I can quickly obtain important information. So you say, that only possible way is to call "myProc" like "exec myProc(anotherVariable , 'anotherVariable');. I can declare variable nameVariable='anotherVariable';, but instead of one row I need to code more rows to implement this function....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about two rows; you mean your proc will be two lines of code, or the call will need two lines, or something else? You don't have to declare a variable for the call, you can just pass a literal string. Anyway, yes, I think the only way to do what you seem to want is to pass the name as another variable.

Comment: It's very complex system. I can't redesign it (sigh..). I just must use variable, because it operates with many rows. This variable has standard name, which I can use. Let me exaplain it more clearly. This variable has name, let's say, 'varIDShop' and it's varchar2 variable. It's used many times. I need to operate with table Shop in myProc. That's why I must now use myProc(varIDShop, 'Shop');. Much more simple would be myProc(varIDShop). It's not one occurrence, and not one variable... I just wanted to keep it more simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't determine the name your caller assigned to the variable it passed (as far as I know; maybe you could hack something with PL/Scope but it wold be horrible).

I can see three options, depending on how many variations you need. I'm assuming there aren't many from your comment that the name affects which table the procedure works against.

You could pass the variable name, or the bit you're interested in, as a separate parameter:

```
procedure myProc(variable varchar2, variable_name varchar2) ...
exec myProc(varIDShop, 'Shop');
```

You could finesse that a little with wrapper procedures for each variant:

```
procedure myProc(variable varchar2, variable_name varchar2) ...
procedure myProcShop(variable varchar2) is
begin
  myProc(variable, 'Shop');
end;
/
exec myProcShop(varIDShop);
```

... so your call just has to pick the relevant wrapper function to call.

Or you could declare multiple variables, one for each variant, and only set the one that's relevant:

```
procedure myProc(shop_variable varchar2, office_variable varchar2, ...) ...
exec myProc(shop_variable => varIDShop);
```

... and then test which is set within the procedure.

The last two would both mean your call still only has one argument, but they are a bit more complex, and have potential to use the wrong variable name or procedure name (cut-and-paste errors). Although so does the first, I suppose.

None of those directly use the variable name in the caller though. But on the other hand, you could call any of them, e.g. for testing, without having to declare a variable at all - just passing a string literal:

```
exec myProc('Tesco', 'Shop');
exec myProc(shop_variable => 'Sainsbury');
exec myProcShop('Asda');
```